# How to manage nonstop running threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, java-6

I'm working on a piece of software that should keep n threads running continuously, so I decided to implement the simplest solution I could think of: each of my threads is defined on a class that implements Runnable, and in the main function I start all of them.
Recently, I've observed that one of my threads does not start, so I'm thinking that my code is not safe at all.

This is an example of one of my runnables:

```java
public class ExRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        printLog("ExRunnable started...");
        try {
            while (true) {
                ...
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And, this is how it starts in main:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (readConfigurationData()) {

            Thread exThread = new Thread(new ExRunnable());
            exThread.start();

            ...
        }
        else
            printLog("Invalid configuration data!");
    }
```

I'm starting about 12 threads in my main function, and just one of them seems to not start. 
What I would like to know is if my method is indeed not safe, and if you could provide me with a safer template.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How can you tell that thread is not started? You code looks fine.

Comment: I've called a function printLog that should print a log to a file and the log it's not printed. I'm 100% positive that the function works fine.

Comment: add logging before `exThread.start()` to make sure that you start thread.

Comment: What could cause it not to start?

Comment: `readConfigurationData()` can return `false`

Comment: Are you sure that your `printLog` is thread-safe?

Comment: It doesn't. But, you were right about it not getting started. Only the first 5 of my threads are gettings started. Is this a system limitation?

Comment: You mean `start` is not called? There is limit on number of thread, but with your 12 thread is far from reaching it.

Comment: printLog should be thread safe, it's just a System.out.println with a timestamp concatenated to the message

Comment: Yeap. exThread.start() is not called

Comment: Why? if `readConfigurationData` returns `true` only way it is possible if `new Thread` or `new ExRunnable()` throws exception.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. My fifth thread was throwing an error and that's why there was nothing happening down the line. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to implement is a thread pool. Why not use some of the already existing thread pool implementations that come with java?

For example here is some sample code to have a threadpool of 5 threads and schedule a thread every 1 second:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
System.out.println("Thread running");
}, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

More info in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: I wanted to implement it like this, but I haven't found anything simple for Java SE 6.

Comment: These classes were added in Java 1.5, so they should definitely be present in Java SE 6.

Comment: Ok. I will try your suggestion. Thank you!